# Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "_id" because it is not an "own property" of its parent

Tags: ajax, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm new to JS and Handlebars, and would really appreciate some help with a project I'm working on. I'm using AJAX to create a new category, and am trying to then fetch that category back from the server (currently, if I refresh, the new category disappears. I understand AJAX is asynchronous, and am trying to get a response from the server if possible). Currently, I'm getting the following error:

Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "_id" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.

From the reading I've done, I believe this is happening because Handlebars 4.6.0 and on forbids accessing prototype properties and methods of the context object by default. In order to address this, I installed @handlebars/allow-prototype-access package, but I'm not sure how to use it in my app.engine. Could someone please help? Here's my app.js:

```
const {globalVariables} = require('./config/configuration')

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');
const {mongoDbUrl, PORT} = require('./config/configuration');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const {selectOption} = require('./config/customFunctions');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileUpload');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access');

const app = express();

/* Configure Mongoose to Connect MongoDB */
mongoose.connect(mongoDbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(response => {
        console.log("MongoDB Connected Successfully.", { useNewUrlParser: true });
    }) .catch(err => {
        console.log("Database connection failed", err)
    });



/* Configure express*/
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/*flash and session*/
app.use(session({
    secret: 'anysecret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}))

app.use(flash());

app.use(globalVariables);

app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
  }));

/* Setup View Engine To Use Handlebars */
app.engine('handlebars', hbs({defaultLayout: 'default', helpers: {select: selectOption}}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

/* Method Override Middleware */
app.use(methodOverride('newMethod'));


/* Routes */
const defaultRoutes = require('./routes/defaultRoutes');
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/adminRoutes');

app.use('/', defaultRoutes);
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port 3000`);
})
```

Here is the .handlebars form I am using to create the category:

```
 $("#create-category-button").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var data = $("#category-title").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/category',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {name: data},
                success: function (response) {

                    var html = `<tr>
                        <td>${response.title}</td>
                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <a href="/admin/category/edit/${response._id}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning mr-2">Edit</a>
                            <form action="/admin/category/${response._id}?newMethod=DELETE" method="post">
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>`;

                        console.log(response);
                    $(".category-list").append(html);

                }
            });

            $("#category-title").val('');
        });
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I had to adjust me app.engine as below:

```
app.engine('handlebars', hbs( {defaultLayout: 'default', helpers: {select: selectOption}, handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(_handlebars)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to rewrite the object. On my case:

```js
router.post('/getMessage', async (req, res) => {

    const dbMessageData = await Message.findByPk(req.body.message_id,);
    console.log("---> dbMessageData :" + JSON.stringify(dbMessageData));
    const  message  = {
        "id": dbMessageData.id,
        "title": dbMessageData.title,
        "content": dbMessageData.content,
        "user_id": dbMessageData.user_id,
        "UserId": dbMessageData.user_id
    }
         console.log("---> message :" + JSON.stringify (message) );
    res.render('updateMessage', {message, session: req.session});

});
```

In this way, you do not have to mess with unnecessary config issues.